# Report Viewer parameters are not aligned when viewed in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, alignment, report, reportviewer

I have a report that in design is aligned all parameters and textbox.
  When I run the app, it shows all itens messed.

```
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body, form { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
</style>


<form id="form1" runat="server" >
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptguia" runat="server" Height="100%" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" Width="100%">
    <LocalReport ReportEmbeddedResource="LadySys.report.guia_consulta.rdlc" ReportPath="report\guia_consulta.rdlc">
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>   
</form>
```